# Task Queue error with task : Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

I write component witch some caching functionallity. It is based on async storage.

```
 static getDiscounts(categoryAndPage) {
 return AsyncStorage.getItem(categoryAndPage);
}
```

so It returning a promise. So inside my funtion I call `then` on this promise.

```
 makeRemoteRequest() {
    this.setState({loading: true});

    const page = this.state.page;
    const catId = this.props.navigation.state.params.categoryId;

    var discountCacheKey = `${catId}_${page}`;

    var discountsPromise = DiscountsCache.getDiscounts(discountCacheKey);

    discountsPromise.then(cachedDiscounts => {
        if (cachedDiscounts !== null) {
            this.setState({
                discounts: page === 1
                    ? cachedDiscounts
                    : [
                        ...this.state.discounts,
                        ...cachedDiscounts
                    ],
                loading: false
            })
        }
```

In render function I have `FlatList` component which is based on `this.state.discounts`

```
 <FlatList
          data={this.state.discounts}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
          var media = item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]; <--- here I get error.
...
```

Previously without caching and promises everything was fine.

Error:

> TaskQueue: Error with task : Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined

Comment: what's the value of this.state.discounts? I think you might need to parse the json before using it .

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just forgot to parsed it but it doesn't matter. I still have this error. I check the data and its ok. I thnik problem is with Promise.

Comment: I get this warning before exception also
```Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined```

Comment: add catch block to handle promise rejection. Your error simply says **item._embedded** is undefined. So you can't access to wp:featuredmedia property of an undefined. Post the value of item by console.log(item).

Comment: Okay, I found it. I just adding emtpy arrays to my cache..